# How can i remove a object from an array?

Tags: python, list, object

How can I delete an object by looking for the property / attribute of the object?

I want that when adding several objects to a list I can search for example by the attribute code and delete only that object

How could I do it?

```
class Biblioteca():
    def cargarMateriales(self,material,a):
        material.append(a)
        return material
    def cargarPersonas(self):
        print()

class Material(Biblioteca):
    def __init__(self,tipoMaterial=None,codigo=None,autor=None,titulo=None,anio=None,status=None):
        self.tipoMaterial = tipoMaterial
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.autor = autor
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.anio = anio
        self.status = status
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Tipo de materia: {0}, Codigo: {1}, Autor del libro: {2}, Titulo del libro: {3}, Año del libro: {4}, status del libro: {5}".format(self.tipoMaterial,self.codigo,self.autor,self.titulo,self.anio,self.status)
    def altaMaterial(self):
        self.tipoMaterial = input(str("Cual es el tipo de material?"))
        self.codigo = input(str("Que codigo tiene el libro codigo?"))
        self.autor = input(str("Que autor tiene el libro?"))
        self.titulo = input(str("Que titulo tiene el libro?"))
        self.anio = int(input("De que año es?"))
        self.status = input(str("Que status tiene?"))

material = []
b = Biblioteca()
a = Material()
a.altaMaterial()
b.cargarMateriales(material, a)
```

Comment: The relationship of your code and of your question is not clear. What is the list of objects, what is the property or attribute you want to consider, and which value of that property/attribute is the indicator to delete the object? Also, do you want to delete all objects with the particular property/attribute value, or just the first?

Comment: The list of objects is material. The property will be the indicator to delete the objetct is codigo from object Material. I want that when searching for the code attribute delete all the records with the code attribute @RoryDaulton

Answer (score 0):

For findig the elements that matches a criteria in a list you can use this one-line expression:

```
elements = [element for element in my_list if element.code == code]
```

Where `code` is a variable that contains the code you are searching. This would return all the elements that maches, could be an empty list if no one matches, a list with one element if there is only one element that maches the condition or more than one. If you only need the first element that matches the criteria you can use the `next` function like this:

```
element = next(element for element in my_list if element.code == code)
```

Once you have the element you can remove it from the list like this:

```
my_list.remove(element)
```

Comment: it didnt work for me, error ->`elements = [element for element in material if element['codigo'] == prova]
TypeError: 'Material' object is not subscriptable` @Constantine32

Comment: Yeah sorry, you have to change `element['codigo']` by `element.codigo`

Answer (score 0):

The **filter** function allows you to select certain elements from a list:

```
for i in range(15):
    materiales.append(Material(tipoMaterial=i%4, codigo=i))

print(materiales)

materiales = list(filter(lambda material: material.tipoMaterial < 2, materiales))

print(materiales)
```

Hence you can match those that specify some criteria.